# website doesn't work unless connected to VPN

Tags: dns

This issue seems strange, but everytime I access my website (http://jbrconsultancy.org/)
without VPN it displays `"This site has been suspended."`

When I connect to a VPN it seems to work fine, I am currently residing here in the Philippines, I'm not sure whether this is an ISP problem or anything else.

The website works fine before I transferred the domain name to a different domain provider. I am sure that I properly transferred and configured my domain.
I am able to use my email under that domain. The only thing that's making it difficult is the website part.

I've been trying to figure out the problem for almost a day now.
I tried clearing my browser histories from FireFox, Chrome and MS Edge.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working ok from the UK, the domain resolves as `173.208.146.234`. Try flushing your browser cache, or switching to a different DNS.

Comment: This is my major problem (with my website, https://freebrowsingeeks.com). I made a transfer of domain from Interserver to Namecheap. Now, from Nigeria,  I need to connect to VPN to even operate my site's Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

DNS is a global distributed system, and apparently the old IP address is still being returned by some DNS servers somewhere (including the one that your network or ISP uses). It should update sooner or later.

Before switching hosts it is recommended to decrease the "TTL" (Time to live) value to a short period (minutes), so DNS servers will not cache the old IP address for a long time. After the switch is done you should set TTL high again, so inter-server traffic stays low.

Comment: this is probably the reason. I tried accessing the website from a different computer using a different ISP.. the website seems to work fine now..